# How to run python pipe command using Java Process?

Tags: java, python, pipe

I would like to run a python command within Java.

The format of the command is as follows:

```
python abc.py TAG < xyz.txt
```

When I use Java's Process:

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python abc.py TAG < xyz.txt");
```

I get an incorrect argument error because the `< xyz.txt` is being interpreted as arguments to `abc.py` as opposed to the terminal meaning of piping `xyz.txt`.

Is there any way to run a java command that has the piping functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec()` does not involve a shell. You can't do things like that.

You either need to `exec()` a shell and have *it* run the python process as you're trying, or you need to `exec()` the python process, open and read the `xyz.txt` file with Java, then send the data to the exec'd process' standard in (You can get that stream from the `Process` object).